# Counting the contents of a directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I know how I would approach counting the number of files in a directory- I would use a `for filename in *` loop and then test the files names to fit my purpose, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop through a directory and then count how many (sub)directories are in it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think I'd use something on the order of: `find . -maxdepth 0 -type d -print | wc`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to count files or subdirectories? Do you want to count files *in* subdirectories, or just top-level files?

Comment: My whole scripts purpose it this: I want to let a user pass in a directory name, change to that directory, and count the number of directories in that directory and the number of files and whether they're `-e`, `-r` or `-w`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if its a directory by using `-d`.

You can use find: `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

Answer (score 1):

```
((n=0))
for fn in *
do
   [[ -d "${fn}" ]] && ((n=1+${n}))
done
```

Keep a counter and only increment it for directories...

Comment: So `for fn in *` loops through the names of the directories too?

Comment: Also, not to show too much of my newbness, what's up with the extra brackets and parans?

Comment: Yes, `*` matches everything in the current directory (except stuff that starts with `.`). The double square brackets are roughly equivalent to an in-shell version of `test` or `[`, and so somewhat more efficient. The double parentheses are used to mark math expressions and evaluate them as such. Read `man bash` for more info...

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Take a look at the `wc` command. Specifically `wc -l` which counts the number of lines in the output. You can use a whole array of commands that generate output and then pipe that to the `wc -l`. Be careful of commands that add headers and footers to the files (like `ls -l`).

Here are some examples:

This will count all files and directories that don't start with `.`:

```
$ ls | wc -l
```

It's the same as your for loop you had in your question.

This will count all files and directories including those *hidden* ones. Note the `ls -A` instead of `ls -a`. The first won't list `.` and `..` as files while the second will:

```
$ ls -A | wc -l
```

This will count all files and directories in the entire directory tree

```
$ find . | wc -l
```

This will only count the directories in the whole directory tree

```
$ find . -type d| wc -l
```

This will count all the files in the whole directory tree

```
$ find . -type f | wc -l
```

ls -
This will limit you to the number of directories in the current directory

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
```

And, you can use this to assign it to a variable:

```
$ num_of_files=$(find . -type f | wc -l)
```

Comment: Hm this is very interesting. Are there ways to add flags, such as to check how many executable files there are?

Comment: @ConnorBlack Take a look at the manpages of the find command. A quick check shows the `-executable` flag as a parameter: `find . -executable -type f`. Type `man find` at the command line prompt. Dive right in and don't let the documentation intimidate you.

Answer (score 0):

here is how count directories or do stuff with directory names.

```
#!/bin/bash

old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n' 
array=($(ls -F /foo/bar/ | grep '/$')) # this creates an array named "array" that holds
IFS=$old_IFS                           # all the directory names located in /foo/bar/

echo ${#array[@]} # this will give you the number of directories in /foo/bar/

for ((i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++))
do
echo ${array[$i]} # this will output a list of all the directories
done
```

alternatively you could:

```
ls -F /foo/bar/ | grep '/$' | cat > directorynames.txt
```

and then count the number of lines. or you could get rid of the cat and just put the above in a for loop that would count up for every newline character.